# How to Route google apps gmail based on subject line?

Tags: email, routing, g-suite

I set up a bunch of routes in my new google apps system (migrating from doing inbound email with mailgun forwarding).

In one case we need to forward all email with a particular subject to another address, but it's not clear how to do that in google apps.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368153?hl=en

in mailgun, i can do

```
match_header("subject", "cancel")
```

with

```
forward("me@example.com")
```

but in google apps, it seems like i can only do recipient based routing.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Everything I've found says this isn't possible, which seems like a massive oversight. You can, however, forward all your mail to a standards GMail account and then use filters to forward mail to the right place based on the subject line.

Comment: It's pretty archaic. @jxmallett that seems like the most feasible solution outside of writing new software to handle forwards.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is very old, but in case someone runs into this, as I have, there is a relatively simple way to accomplish it via :
Apps >Google Workspace>Settings for Gmail>Compliance

Simply add a new rule to Content Compliance and use advanced matching option to specifically select Subject Line. Then you will basically have the same options as you do in Default Routing to add/substitute recipients and the rest of it, but now based on matching your rules and not just the recipient like in the Default Routing

Comment: This is accurate and useful in 2023, and pretty simple to do. There are also other custom routing rules under 'Compliance'.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to filter and route emails from account settings, which is subscribed to the group

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2707558?hl=en

You can create custom Google account, subscribe it to the group, then create a filter and forwarding in the account.